# how to add logical operators?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators, control-flow

I have been trying to work this issue of on Codecademy all day. Nothing I do seems to work.

Instructions: 
"Add some if/else statements to your cases that check to see whether one condition and another condition are true, as well as whether one condition or another condition are true. Use && and || at least one time each."

This is the code I previously entered:

```
var user = prompt("What is your name?").toUpperCase();

switch(user) {
    case 'Sam':
        console.log("Hi, Sam");
        break;
    case 'John':
        console.log("Hi, John");
        break;
    case 'Mary':
        console.log("Hi, Mary");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("I don't know you. What is your name?");
}
```

Comment: It says "add if/else statements", so add those.

Comment: `user` will never be equal to one of those names, because anything you enter is set to Upper Case.

Comment: I understand it's just a demo application you but "I don't know you. What is your name?" after you've just asked it... it's weird.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't have any `if/else` statements. How about something like this:

```
var user = prompt("What is your name?").toUpperCase();

// If user is known, greet him
if (user === "SAM" || user === "JOHN" || user === "MARY") {
  console.log("Hi, " + user)
}
// Otherwise apologize because we are polite
else {
  console.log("Sorry " + user + ", I don't know you.");
}

// If user is neither John nor Sam, ask about them
if (user !== "JOHN" && user !== "SAM") {
  console.log("By the way, how are John and Sam doing?");
}
```

Comment: +I for a great example and a comment that made me smile _`Otherwise apologize because we are polite`_

Answer (score 0):

1. `.toUpperCase()` transforms a string to uppercase letters, so it would be ‘SAM’, ‘JOHN’ etc.

Change it to something like this:

```
String.prototype.capitalizeFirstLetter = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

var user = prompt("What is your name?").capitalizeFirstLetter()
```

2. What conditions do you need to test?

   ```
   switch(user) {
   case 'Sam':
       if ( someCondition || anotherCondition ) { 
               // do something
       } else { // do something 
       }
       console.log("Hi, Sam");
       break;

   case 'John':
       console.log("Hi, John");
       break;

   case 'Mary':
       console.log("Hi, Mary");
       break;

   default:
       console.log("I don't know you. What is your name?”);
   }
   ```